# Add keypoint Extraction Post-Processing Layer to TensorFlow Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pose-detection, movenet

I have `PoseNet Tensorflow` saved model that takes in an image and outputs heatmap and offset tensors.

PoseNet is an `already trained model` from Google, and I've very little control over it. the model works fine, but I just want to `add a layer to it that performs the post-processing`.

Currently, I'm extracting the final keypoints in Python code. **How can I add post-processing layer to the model itself so it outputs the final keypoints?**

There are models, such as [Movenet](https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/movenet), that output the final keypoint, and I want to do the same thing for PoseNet.

This image illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

I've looked at the following posts about adding post-processing layer, but I don't know how to apply it for my problem:

1. [How to add post-processing into a Tensorflow Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030626/how-to-add-post-processing-into-a-tensorflow-model?rq=2)
2. [Cannot add layers to saved Keras Model. 'Model' object has no attribute 'add'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755022/cannot-add-layers-to-saved-keras-model-model-object-has-no-attribute-add)
3. [How to add another layer on a pre-loaded network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660613/how-to-add-another-layer-on-a-pre-loaded-network)
4. [Add layer between two layers in saved model tensorflow](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/add-layer-between-two-layers-in-saved-model-tensorflow/18209)

---

I fully understand the post-processing algorithm and have implemented it in Python. Now, I want to integrate this functionality directly into the model itself:

```py
"""
heatmap shape [9, 9, 17]
offset shape [9, 9, 34]
"""
def parse_output(heatmap, offset):
    # Get the number of joints - value is 17 for Posenet
    joint_num = heatmap.shape[-1]
    # Initialize an array to store the keypoints
    pose_kps = np.zeros((joint_num, 3), np.uint32)

    # Iterate over each joint
    for i in range(heatmap.shape[-1]):
        # select heatmap for the i-th joint    
        joint_heatmap = heatmap[..., i]

        # Find the maximum probability and its position
        max_prob = np.max(joint_heatmap)
        # get the x, y coordinates of the max_prob position. eg: [4,7]
        max_val_pos = np.squeeze(np.argwhere(joint_heatmap == max_prob))
       
        # scale keypoints to the model input coordinates
        remap = np.array(max_val_pos/8*257, dtype=np.int32)
        
        # Assign the calculated values to the keypoints array
        pose_kps[i, 0] = remap[0] + offset[max_val_pos[0], max_val_pos[1], i]
        pose_kps[i, 1] = remap[1] + offset[max_val_pos[0], max_val_pos[1], i + joint_num]
        pose_kps[i, 2] = max_prob

    return pose_kps
```

---

The above `parse_output` make sense to me and similar implementation is also done in the following projects:

1. [How to parse the heatmap output for the pose estimation tflite model?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60105770/7234479)
2. [decodeSinglePose](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/f27de99cebefc5facd33f3d61b536c0402df08e2/posenet/src/single_pose/decode_single_pose.ts#L57-L94)

---

I have created a sample [PosetNetDemo](https://github.com/leoull/poseNetDemo/blob/main/poseNetDemo.py) project to show my current implementation.

I appreciate it if you point me to a resource or help me solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your decoding function can be vectorized relatively straightforwardly. There's a lot of casting around because of TensorFlow stricter type requirement, to keep the result between your decoding function  and my TensorFlow version similar. I also took the liberty to add a batch dimension to the function, as it will play better if you want to incorporate it in a Keras model.

**Vectorized function:**

```
def parse_output_tf(hm, offset):
    batch, height, width, nkpts = tf.unstack(tf.shape(hm))
    # We flatten and transpose to look for the max value for each joint, as topk works on the last dimension
    scores = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(hm, (batch, -1, nkpts)), (0, 2, 1))
    max_prob, max_inds = tf.math.top_k(scores, k=1)

    # getting back x,y coordinates
    max_xs = tf.cast(max_inds % width, tf.float32)
    max_ys = tf.cast(max_inds // width, tf.float32)
    # to index, it's easier if the offset array has the same shape as the score, so we can use
    # tf.gather transparently
    offset = tf.transpose(
        tf.reshape(offset, (batch, -1, tf.shape(offset)[-1])), (0, 2, 1)
    )
    offset_ys = tf.gather(offset[:, :nkpts, ...], max_inds, batch_dims=2)
    offset_xs = tf.gather(offset[:, nkpts:, ...], max_inds, batch_dims=2)
    # now we can calculate the final coordinates with the offset
    xs = tf.cast(tf.math.floor(max_xs / 8 * 257) + offset_xs, tf.int32)
    ys = tf.cast(tf.math.floor(max_ys / 8 * 257) + offset_ys, tf.int32)
    max_prob = tf.cast(max_prob, tf.int32)
    return tf.concat([ys, xs, max_prob], axis=-1)
```

You can check that the output of the two functions are similar (Due to casting/precision issues, there might be slightly different results, so I would encourage to test with a floating type instead, i.e remove the cast/flooring functions and do the same in your numpy implementation):

```
for _ in range(100):
    hm = np.random.uniform(size=(16, 9, 9, 17)).astype(np.float32)
    offset = np.random.uniform(size=(16, 9, 9, 34)).astype(np.float32)

    out_tf = parse_output_tf(hm, offset)
    out_np = np.stack([parse_output(h, o) for h,o in zip(hm, offset)],axis=0)
    assert np.allclose(out_tf, out_np)
```

---

**Using it in a Keras model:**

You can simply use a [Lambda Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda):

```
model = Model(inputs, [out_heatmap, out_offset])
decoding_layer = Lambda(parse_output_tf)
decoded_pred = decoding_layer(model.outputs)
model_with_post = Model(model.inputs, decoded_pred)
```

If you want to run the model on accelerated hardware, you might run into issues due to the use of `tf.shape` which is not always handled well by static folding optimizations. If that's the case, you might either want to create an actual Keras layer where you pre-compute those values [during the building phase](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/#best-practice-deferring-weight-creation-until-the-shape-of-the-inputs-is-known), or simply hardcode the values in your function.

---

**Implementation Details:**

I chose to use `tf.math.topk` to get the maximum scores for each keypoints and tf.gather to do the indexing, but there are other methods that would work. Using `topk` has the advantage to scale to multi-joint detection if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. How exactly do I add this layer to the `poseNet model`? the above code has `model = Model(inputs, [out_heatmap, out_offset])`, is this creating a new model?

Comment: I missed the fact that you have only a tflite model. As far as I'm aware, this is not something you can do. You either need to get a TensorFlow / Keras model, or recreate its topology and load the weights from the tflite file. You can also create a tflite model from my code and chain the two models call, but that's a bit janky.

Comment: I also have tfjs layered model, I load it using [tf.loadLayersModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load#loading_a_tfmodel). can I add the layer to the layered model?

Comment: Not that I know unfortunately